# What is the meaning of 货色 in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

货色 either means just goods or kinds and quality of goods, I believe.

货 is 货物 I think.
色 is either 颜色 or 特色

这是一座文化超级市场，新奇货色的不时出现对在寻求知识的顾客带有强烈诱惑。

新奇货色：goods of novel type and appearance or just novel goods???

How to translate 新奇货色?

Comment: It can be both, newer types, styles, and appearances, that have never been seen before, than the existing goods in the display.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate "货色" to "stuffs".

Comment: So how would you translate the whole sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Explanations on 汉典 ([www.zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net))

**货色**:

**(1)** [goods]∶商品的品种或质量

- 上等货色

**(2)** [rubbish]∶比喻人或思想言论、作品等(含贬义)

- 修正主义货色

**(3)** [stuff]∶价值不大的著作、演说或主意

- 小说里充满无聊的货色

**(4)** [property and beauty/appearance]∶财货和美色

---

英语 goods, (derog.)​ stuff, trash